# Importing a database using SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

apologies for how simple this question will be to followers of the SQl and SSH tags.

I would like to upload a copied database into a new database.

I created a copy of a data base I'd like to duplicate into my root folder. My root folder now contains a file "sitename_duplicate" with all the data.

In my web host control panel I created a new database "20130924_sitename"

I cannot seem to upload the contents of sitename_duplicate into 20130923_sitename.

```
mysql -u myname -p sitename_duplicate < 20130923_sitename.sql
-bash: 20130923_sitename.sql: No such file or directory

mysql -u myname -p 20130923_sitename < sitename_duplicate.sql
-bash: sitename_duplicate.sql: No such file or directory
```

The database with the data is sitename_duplicate and it's in the root. The blank and newly created database is 20130923_sitename.

How do I move the contents of sitename_duplicate into 20130923_sitename using SSH?

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking here -- since you take about ssh and your web host control panel, I assume you have two hosts?  where are your files?  where are you executing the commands you report?  can you be a little clearer?

Comment: If `sitename_duplicate` is created with `mysqldump`, and it's called that, just drop that `.sql`... (tab completion of file names is your friend). `mysql -u myname -p 20130923_sitename < sitename_duplicate`. Note that this assumes the file is in your current working dir.

Comment: @Simon appologies for any confusion. Nope, just one host. For some reason they do not support importing into SQL via PHPMyAdmin and told me to SSH. So, I created the blank database int he control panel called 20130923_sitename. Then, I duplicated the database I want to copy into the root: mysqldump -u myname databasetobecopied_name -p > sitename_duplicate.sql. Where are my files? The duplicated file is in my root, I just want to upload it into the newly created blank db called 20130923_sitename

Comment: @Wrikken no 20130923_sitename is created in my host control panel - I just added a new database. All I wantt o do is upload the contents of sitename_duplicate into it.

Comment: Well, if it's says no such file, there is no such file. Either it's in another directory or you are misspelling its filename.

Comment: Looks like cutting of the file extension .sql did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is

```
mysql -u username -pPassword --host hostname database_name < dump.sql
```

So it should be for you:

```
mysql -u myname -pMyPassword 20130924_sitename < sitename_duplicate
```

Comment: thanks seems to have gotten me a step further except that now I receive a message "Access denied for user 'myname'@'localhost' to database '20130924_sitename'" 
Sigh

Comment: note that there is no blank between the -p and the password. And it's quite likely that your database host is not localhost but something else like mysql5.mydomain.com. Check your provider's documentation.